# GCD serial queue like approach using swift async/await api?

Tags: swift, async-await

I am adopting the new `async/await` Swift API. Things work great.
Currently in my apps I am using GCD serial queues as a pipeline to enforce tasks to happen serially.

For manipulating data of some critical models in the app I use a serial queue accessible from anywhere in the app:

```
let modelQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.myapp.updatemodelqueue")
```

Anytime a model needs to modify some model data I dispatch to that queue:

```
modelQueue.async {
        // ... model updates
}
```

With the new `async/await` changes I am making I still want to force model actual updates to happen serially. So, for example, when I import new model data from the server I want to make sure they happen serially.

For example, I may have a call in my model that looks like this:

```
func updateCarModel() async {
    
    let data = await getModelFromServer()
    
    modelQueue.async {
        
        // update model
        
    }

}
```

Writing that function using that pattern however would not wait for the model update changes because of the `modelQueue.async`. I do not want to use `modelQueue.sync` to avoid deadlocks.

So then after watching WWDC videos and looking at documentation I implemented this way, leveraging `withCheckedContinuation`:

```
func updateCarModel() async {
    
    let data = await getModelFromServer()
    
    
    await withCheckedContinuation({ continuation in
        modelQueue.async {
            
            // update model
         
            continuation.resume()
        }
    })
    
}
```

However, to my understanding `withCheckedContinuation` is really meant to allow us to incrementally transition to fully adopt the new `async/await` Swift API. So, it does not seem to be what I should use as a final approach.

I then looked into `actor`, but I am not sure how that would allow me to serialize any model work I want to serialize around the app like I did with a static queue like shown above.

So, how can I enforce my model around the app to do model updates `serially` like I used to while also fully adopting the new await/async swift API without using `withCheckedContinuation`?

Comment: Actors do precisely this, allowing you to perform asynchronous update of some model objects within async-await paradigm, but eliminates need for you to manually synchronize with a serial queue (or any other homespun synchronization mechanism). It does the synchronization for you.

Comment: yes, I agree. I'm just trying to understand how I would architect things properly. Is it a global actor? The nice thing about the queue is that from anywhere in the app I could dispatch on it and be done. So, that's why I looked into actor, but not sure how actually solve with it to provide a similar approach to the app-wide serial queue...

Comment: The problem with using actors is you can only use non-async function on the actor to create a serial queue. If you use a function marked async, other code can run during suspension, which makes it non-serial.

Comment: I have a similar question. In the Concurrency Behind the Scenes talk, they had an example of using an Actor in lieu of a serial Database queue. But they state that there is no longer a happens-before/FIFO guarantee on Actor calls, unlike what you get with a serial queue (Dispatch or Operation).

Answer (score 3):

By making the model an `actor`, Swift synchronizes access to it' shared mutable state. If the model is written like this:

```swift
actor Model {
    var data: Data
    
    func updateModel(newData: Data) {
        data = newData
    }
}
```

The `updateModel` function here is synchronous, it's execution is uninterrupted after it's invoked. Because Model is an actor, Swift restricts you to treat it as if you are calling an asynchronous funtion from the outside. You'd have to `await`, which results in suspension of your active thread.

If in case you'd want to make `updateModel` async, the code within will always be synchronous unless if you explicitly suspend it by calling await. The order of execution of multiple `updateModel` calls is not very deterministic. As far as you don't suspend within the `updateModel` block, it is sure that they execute serially. In such case, there is no use making the `updateModel` async.

Answer (score 2):

If your update model code is synchronous you can make your model `actor` type to synchronize access. Actors in swift behave similar to serial DispatchQueue, they perform only one task at a time in the order of submission. However, current swift actors are re-entrant, which means if you are calling any `async` method actor suspends the current task until the async function completes and proceeds to process other submitted tasks.

If your update code is asynchronous, using an actor might introduce data race. To avoid this, you can wait for [non-reentrant actor support](https://github.com/DougGregor/swift-evolution/blob/actors/proposals/nnnn-actors.md#non-reentrancy) in swift. Or you can try this workaround [`TaskQueue`](https://github.com/SwiftyLab/AsyncObjects/blob/main/Sources/AsyncObjects/TaskQueue.swift) I have created to synchronize between asynchronous tasks or use [other synchronization mechanisms that are also created by me](https://github.com/SwiftyLab/AsyncObjects).